# Нужно сделать сферу при касание которой и нажатия игрока левой кнопки мыши, персонаж должен подпрыгнуть

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-android

Я начал делать свою первую игру и пытаюсь разнообразить геймплей, решил сделать сферу прыжка как в Geometry Dash.
дело в том, что персонаж кликами мыши меняет гравитацию
сам прыжок работает но если гравитация == -1 и персонаж подлетает к сфере он подпрыгивает вверх:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
а должно:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rafd.png
заранее спасибо !!!
вот код:

```
   public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Orb" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        //только в одну сторону :)
        rb.AddForce(OrbJumpVector * OrbJumpForce);    
        rb.gravityScale *= -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать проверять какой rb.gravityScale стоит и исходя из его значений делать прыжок вверх или вниз

```
    public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    { 
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Orb" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            if(rb.gravityScale > 0) 
                rb.AddForce(OrbJumpVector * OrbJumpForce);
            else 
                rb.AddForce(-OrbJumpVector * OrbJumpForce);   // вектор с отрицательным значением 
            rb.gravityScale *= -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ответ, который дал Максим, ниже, будет лучше

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно что-то типа этого:

```
...
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Orb" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)) {
    rb.AddForce(OrbJumpVector * OrbJumpForce * rb.gravityScale);    
    rb.gravityScale *= -1;
}
...
```

То есть мы либо домножаем на 1 (оставляем как есть), либо на -1 (переворачиваем) вектор силы.
Это работает только если модуль гравитации всегда равен 1, то есть rb.gravityScale = {-1, 1}